# old ASPX page does not work after upgrading to ASP.NET MVC 5 and NET 4.5.1

Tags: webforms, asp.net-mvc-5, .net-4.5

I had ASP.NET web application which combining MVC4 and WebForms and .NET 4.5.0. I have upgraded to MVC5 and .NET 4.5.1.

The ASPX pages stopped to work (Error 500).

```
FileLoadException
    TargetSite = Void GetTypeByName(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.StackCrawlMarkHandle, IntPtr, Boolean, System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ObjectHandleOnStack)
    Source = mscorlib
    StackTrace =    at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMarkHandle stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
       at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.GetTypeByName(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean reflectionOnly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean loadTypeFromPartialName)
       at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetType(String typeName, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
       at System.Web.Configuration.ConfigUtil.GetType(String typeName, String propertyName, ConfigurationElement configElement, XmlNode node, Boolean checkAptcaBit, Boolean ignoreCase)


Is there something different in ASP.NET MVC 5 with old ASPX WebForms pages?
```

**EDIT:**

I was not able solved this issue and I have reverted all changes and moved back to MVC4 an .NET 4.5.0.

Comment: What is the type of the exception, and what is the error message?

Comment: I have update question, it is Error 500 and FileLoadException.

Comment: What is the exact text of the error message?  Is it something like "Couldn't find file xyz."?

Comment: IIS is serving Custom Error 500 page.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you off in the right direction:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

OR

If your doing a file upload somewhere and you're using a FileStream, make sure you're properly closing the stream before trying to use OleDb... if you don't close the stream, the file will remain locked.

Comment: I have followed exactly this document. Everything involving MVC is working well, but none ASPX pages does not work. There is no upload, nor filestream.